Using vite, how to execute a custom build command once any file has been changed
I'm using vite + typescript + vue3, and there is a command build like below.
I want to trigger the build command once there is a file changed, how can I achieve it besides manually installing the nodemon.
BTW, both vue-tsc and vite build support --watch individually.
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
},


vue-tsc --watch && vite build --watch does not work?

This won't work, these two are a set of operations.

My bad. Have posted what i found to be working on my device

To trigger the build command in your Vite + TypeScript + Vue 3 project whenever a file changes, you can use chokidar-cli to watch your files and run the build script automatically. This way, you avoid manually installing and configuring nodemon.
    {
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "watch-build": "chokidar 'src/**/*' -c 'npm run build'"
  }
}

Now just
npm run watch-build
You can also use fs.watch or debounce

but i have to install chokidar...

yes go for it npm install chokidar-cli --save-dev

Thanks, I have already voted up your answer, and I am waiting for a way without installing any new dependencies.

For non windows:
You can use &:
vue-tsc & vite build

This will make first command run in background, and then run the second.
I have tested in my local setup. While it does not open two terminals, it is easy to distinguish between the two processes as there is numbering in front of the output.

These 2 run in parallel, what I want is a sequential behavior. Every time there is a file updated, run vue-tsc first and then execute the vite build.
